# Why doesn't event delegation work with jquery on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-delegation

I am using latest jQuery which says `.live()` is deprecated and `.on()` should be used instead.
I am having problem attaching click event to the button. I modify the button value dynamically and should be able to handle the two cases

```
<input type="text" ><input id="button_1" type="button" value="add" >
<input type="text"> <input id="button_2" type="button" value="add">

$('[id^="button_"]').on("click", "input", function() {
    $(this).val("delete");
    
    $('#button_'+$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]).attr('id', 'delButton_'+$(this).attr('id').split[1]);
                                                     
});

$('[id^="delButton_"]').on("click", "input", function() {
    $(this).val("add");
    
    $('#delButton_'+$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]).attr('id', 'button_'+$(this).attr('id').split[1]);
    
});
```

This is the demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vC7zE/1/)

Comment: Bacause you can't have nested inputs, if that's what you think you have. You can only delegate to ancestors.

Comment: `'[id^="button_"]'` should be a parent element, not the same element.

Comment: @bfavaretto input elements don't need to be closed. *edit* oh wait I see what you mean.

Comment: It's important to understand that `.on()` is **not** a drop-in replacement for `.live()` - the semantics are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only delegate events to *ancestor* elements, but you're trying to delegate to a sibling. (Actually, I'm not sure what you're doing!)

So if your markup was

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <input type="text" ><input id="button_1" type="button" value="add" >
</div>
```

You could use

```
$('.buttonContainer').on("click", "input", function() {
    // here, "this" will be the clicked input
});
```

The above will delegate clicks on both the text input and the button to their parent div. Clicking on any of the elements will trigger the function.

If you only want to target the button, change the selector passed to `.on`:

```
$('.buttonContainer').on("click", '[id^="button_"]', function() {
    // here, "this" will be the clicked button
});
```

Comment: I see, is there any work around for what I am trying to do. I have this requirement to either add or delete the name of the person.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to add a new div, just delegate to the closest container that exists at the time of the binding. In the worst case, that would be `document`.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of:

```
$('[id^="button_"]').live("click", function() {
```

Is:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id^="button_"]', function() {
```

But if you can use a closer ancestor than `$(document)`, you should.